# Iterate two Lists in struts2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, iterator, nested-loops

I have two lists, `selectedFields` which contains the headers (eg:`id`, `username`, `firstname`) and `custDetails` which contains customer details(eg:`id`,`username`,`firstname`,`birthdate`,`address` etc.). what I want to do here is print only the data from `custDetails` in `<td>` which are contained in `selectedFields`.if selectedFields contains username then only the username values will be shown like `<td>John</td>` and header will be like `<th>username</th>`.

```
<table>
<thead>
  <!-- Selected Fields contains id,username -->
  <s:iterator value="selectedFields">                                           
  <th><s:property/></th>
  </s:iterator>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <!-- custDetails contains id,username,firstname,lastname,address,city,state etc. -->
  <s:iterator value="custDetails" status="custDetails">
    <tr>
    <s:iterator value="selectedFields" status="selectedFields">
    <!-- Display only id,username columns from custDetails since selectedFields contains these values -->  
    <td><s:property value="<s:property />"/></td>
    </s:iterator>
    </tr>
  </s:iterator>                               
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Build what you want to display on the Java side; keep the view layer simple.

Comment: @DaveNewton is it possible to do this way?

Comment: Too much iterators, what do you iterate?

Comment: I want to iterate custDetails(id,username,firstname,lastname,birthdate,address,city,state,country) which contains 3 records but only display columns which are contained in selectedFields(id,username). custDetails: List<Customer>   selectedFields: List<String>

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but it's difficult to read, maintain, and test.

Comment: What do you want to do with columns? Do you want to modify it dynamically?

Comment: This table is generated based on users selection of columns that is stored in selectedFields. @RomanC I don't have to modify them dynamically,just kind of a report to show to user based on columns he selects.Could have shown you a screen but not enough reputation... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` and `else` tags to choose which columns you want to display. Unless you don't want to iterate the object properties.

```
<s:iterator var="sf" value="selectedFields">
  <!-- Display only id,username columns from custDetails since selectedFields contains these values --> 
  <s:if test="#sf == 'id'"> 
   <td><s:property value="id"/></td>
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
  <s:if test="#sf == 'username'"> 
   <td><s:property value="username"/></td>
  </s:if>
  </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```